# HTML issue with images

Tags: html, image, background-image

I have the following problem:
I'm currently making a web site using html and css. I have constructed the background like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div.background {
        width: 500px;
        height: 250px;
        background: url(klematis.jpg) repeat;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      div.transbox {
        width: 400px;
        height: 180px;
        margin: 30px 50px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid black;
        opacity:0.6;
        filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
      }
      div.transbox p {
        margin: 30px 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="background">
      <div class="transbox">
        <p>
          This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
          This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
          This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
          This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
          This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And, of course, I want to put additionally pictures in the box but you can see through them and you are able to see the background image, so the pictures look pale and transperant. How can I make different background color only for the pictures in order to look solid???

Answer (score 0):

You can set a background for an image by setting `background` properties on an `img` element, e.g.

```
img { background: black; }
```

This overrides the initial value `background: transparent` which lets the page background shine through if the image has transparent areas.

Comment: Try posting code and/or URL that demonstrates what you actually did and explaining a) what you expected to happen, b) what happened.